# Detecting if Material Design Button is clicked

Tags: jquery, material-design, material-components-web

I am trying to run some code when a Material Design Button component is clicked.
Nothing seems to be working... can you help?
I have tried the following:

1. using an onclick when the button is selected, but this doesn't appear to trigger
2. Using Jquery to detect the click - but again this doesn't appear to work.

How do we get buttons to trigger functions( surprisingly this is not listed in the documentation!)

```
<!-- Adding button to add new items-->
          <button class="mdc-fab mdc-fab--extended" id="addItem" onClick="addItem">
            <div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
            <span class="material-icons mdc-fab__icon">add</span>
            <span class="mdc-fab__label">New Task</span>
          </button>
          <!-- End Button -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue.
In the end I used jquery to add an event listener on all items with a specific class.

```js
for(item of data) {
  template = `
     <button pizza-id="${item.pizzaName}" class="order-btn mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
        Order
      </button>
             `
  // Dynamic rendering of the buttons
  $("#root-menu").append(template)
}
// Adding click event listeners on all generated buttons with the class "order-btn"
$(".order-btn").click(orderPizza);
```

Now clicking the button works as expected and calls a function called `orderPizza` with the event as parameter !

*I think that the classic `onClick` attribute doesn't work because the click doesn't really occur on the button itself but rather on the autogenerated `<span>` inside it.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code: 
HTML:

```
<button class="mdc-fab mdc-fab--extended" id="addItem" onClick="addItem(event)">
     <div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
     <span class="material-icons mdc-fab__icon">add</span>
     <span class="mdc-fab__label">New Task</span>
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
function addItem(event){
  alert("clicked")
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for this - but it didn't seem to work. I get no response when the button is clicked